# Editing /system/etc/hosts on Android Emulator in Ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu

I need to add an entry to the `etc/hosts` file on an android emulator.
Following all the advice online, I tried modifying the filesystem as read write through `adb`. Then I would modify the file.

```
su
mount -o rw,remount /system
```

Then I append the `etc/hosts` via cat

```
cat >> /system/etc/hosts
```

I type my text, then press enter. I recieve the following error:

> /system/bin/sh: cat: : Read-only file system

When I try to mount as read, write again, I get an error:

> mount: Read-only file system

Can't figure out what to fix at this point. I have a feeling my filesystem settings is being updated to stay as read only.

I've tried using `adb push` and `adb pull`. It works in different directories, but I can't modify the `/system/etc` directory.

Comment: I may be wrong, but does the emulator not copy the system's `etc/hosts`?

Comment: Nope, only 2 entries exist in the emulators /etc/hosts

Comment: I asked the same question here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38354753/not-able-to-update-etc-hosts-file-on-android-studio-x86-and-x86x64-emulator)